# how to populate data in chart.js

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I'm trying to visualize the following dataset with chart.js

```
var data = 
{
    "count": 2,
    "result": {
        "2020-01-22": {
            "confirmed": 12,
            "deaths": 5,
            "recovered": 4
        },
        "2020-01-23": {
            "confirmed": 20,
            "deaths": 3,
            "recovered": 2
        }
    }
}
```

So far I've figured out how to use the dates as label.

```
  var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
        // The type of chart we want to create
        type: 'line',    
        data: { // mapping the dates as labels
            labels: Object.entries(data.result).map( (item) => item[0]),
            datasets: [{
                label: 'My First dataset',
                backgroundColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
                borderColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
                data: ??
            },{
                label: 'My Second dataset',
                backgroundColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
                borderColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
                data: ??
            },{
                label: 'My Third dataset',
                backgroundColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
                borderColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
                data: ??
            }]
        },    // Configuration options go here
        options: {}
    });
```

I'd like to display the values of 'confirmed', 'deaths' and 'recovered' as three lines within this chart. Therefore I would include **three different datasets** right? How would I access the required information from json as array to **populate the data** arrays?

Thanks for your support

Comment: you need to construct three array from your json data and feed it to chartjs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just map the `key` and `values` to appropriate arrays and consume them as `datasets` and `labels`.

```js
var data = {
  "count": 2,
  "result": {
    "2020-01-22": {
      "confirmed": 12,
      "deaths": 5,
      "recovered": 4
    },
    "2020-01-23": {
      "confirmed": 20,
      "deaths": 3,
      "recovered": 2
    }
  }
}
var dates = Object.keys(data["result"]).map(x => x);
var confirm = Object.values(data.result).map(x => x.confirmed);
var deaths = Object.values(data.result).map(x => x.deaths);
var recovered = Object.values(data.result).map(x => x.recovered);


var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'bar',
  data: {
    labels: dates,
    datasets: [{
        label: 'confirmed',
        data: confirm,
        backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
        borderColor: 'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)',
        borderWidth: 1
      },
      {
        label: 'Deaths',
        data: deaths,
        backgroundColor: 'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',


        borderColor: 'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',

        borderWidth: 1
      }, {
        label: 'recovered',
        data: recovered,
        backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',


        borderColor: 'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',

        borderWidth: 1
      }
    ]
  },
  options: {
    scales: {
      yAxes: [{
        ticks: {
          beginAtZero: true
        }
      }]
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.3/Chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="myChart" width="100" height="50"></canvas>
```